# Получение значений XML методом "подпеременных"

Tags: c#, .net

Есть например XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Response>
  <status type="OK">200</status>
  <Text>Ok</Text>
</Response>
```

Я видел способы получения значений, но все они не в одну строку. Как написать функцию, с помощью которой можно было бы очень просто получать значения, так сказать методом "подпеременных". На примере XML получаю все значения так - Response.status, Response.status.type, Response.Text

Comment: что ещё за `метод "подпеременных"`? Вы его сами придумали? :)

Comment: Да) Я просто не знаю как понятней объяснить. Ну то есть Response затем подтип status

Comment: ну оно понятней не стало от этого. Как, например, вы число 200 из вашего XML получите вашим методом?

Comment: число 200 - Response.status, а тип type="OK" Response.status.type

Comment: если `Response.status` это число, то у него нет поля `Response.status.type`

Comment: ну и да, вы это где использовать собрались? Для чего это вам вообще?

Comment: Чтобы проще получать значения переменных. Мне нужно это для проверки, то есть мне приходит значение, а я должен проверить соответствует ли оно нужному значению в XML

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать фокус с десериализацией. 
Например, определим классы

```
public class Response
{
    public string Text{get;set;}
    public Status status {get;set;}
}

public class Status
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string type { get; set; }
    [XmlTextAttribute]
    public int value{get;set;}
}
```

После считаем XML из строки

```
var XML = 
    @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-16""?>
    <Response>
      <Text>sample text</Text>
      <status type=""OK"">200</status>
    </Response>";

using(var sr = new StringReader(XML))
{
    var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Response));
    var response = (Response)ser.Deserialize(sr);

    Console.WriteLine(response.Text);
    Console.WriteLine(response.status.type);
    Console.WriteLine(response.status.value);   
}
```

Получим на выходе

```
sample text
OK
200
```

Comment: А как подгрузить xml по url?

Comment: @АлександрКиселев это уже совсем другой вопрос, которого вы изначально не задавали, задавайте его отдельно.